# Would like to (if possible) import daily text filename_YYYYMMDD for current day

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA.  In Excel 2010, I would like to (if possible) import daily text filename_YYYYMMDD, but how do you specify the script to pick up the current day?  I have searched everywhere on this site (and others) and I didn't  find anything relevant to start.  Would appreciate any suggestion on what I need to do.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Dim fname as String
fname="filename_" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Sub OpenTextFileTest()
    Dim fs, f As Object
    Dim strPath As String
    strPath = "Filename_" + Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.OpenTextFile(strPath, 1, 0)
    MsgBox (f.readline)
    f.Close
End Sub
```

Also this article on my blog might help you with the date object [Excel VBA Working With Dates](http://software-solutions-online.com/2014/02/21/excel-vba-working-with-dates/)

Comment: This works very well.  I wanted to strPath as a macro to open the file as text format in Excel. I used:   With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;fs", Destination:= _
        Range("$B$2"))                 ' What am I doing wrong?

Comment: now thats a different question. I think it would make more sense if you made a new post about that.